# how to use insert to update columns from another table with user defined function cross apply

Tags: t-sql

The update seems to be working but I also need to insert using the parse names function.

--the update function that seems to be working

```
UPDATE P
SET
     P.First_Name = T.ForeName
    ,P.Middle_Name = T.Middle_Name
    ,P.Last_name = T.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact) T
WHERE C.Key1 = '76-ENR'
AND P.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
```

How to use the function in an insert query. This is what I am trying so far. The error displays. "incorrect syntax near cross"

```
INSERT INTO       SISUnitTest.dbo.PEOPLE p (p.LAST_NAME, p.FIRST_NAME, p.LAST_NAME)
SELECT           T.ForeName, T.Middle_Name, T.Surnname
FROM             CONTACT1 c
WHERE        (c.KEY1 = p.PEOPLE_ID);
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(c.Contact) T
WHERE p.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERPise.

You actually have a number of syntax errors here, as well as what appears to be a misunderstanding.

Firstly, your query has two `WHERE` clauses:

```
FROM             CONTACT1 c
WHERE        (c.KEY1 = p.PEOPLE_ID); --1
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(c.Contact) T
WHERE p.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4 --2
```

EAK TEAM is also right about the semi-colon giving you trouble; that was your original error message.

Beyond that, you are performing an `INSERT` into `SISUnitTest.dbo.People`, which you have *tried* to alias as `P`; but the join conditions in your duplicate `WHERE` clauses seem to be a simple copy & paste from the table in the original update query, which was `PCUnitTest.dbo.People AS P`, so I'm wondering if these conditions might no longer be appropriate.  Does `SISUnitTest.dbo.People` have the same fields as `PCUnitTest.dbo.People`?

If what you want is to insert from `PCUnitTest.dbo.People` and  `GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1` into `SISUnitTest.dbo.People`, then that is possible, but you're going to have to restructure your query to something like this (a couple of your original lines have been commented out because they seem to have mistakes in them):

```
--INSERT INTO SISUnitTest.dbo.PEOPLE p (p.LAST_NAME, p.FIRST_NAME, p.LAST_NAME)
INSERT INTO SISUnitTest.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
SELECT
     T.ForeName
    ,T.Middle_Name
    ,T.Surname
FROM GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1 C
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = C.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(C.Contact) T
WHERE C.Key1 = '76-ENR'
;
--AND P.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4
--This condition is already included in the INNER JOIN three lines up
```

It's worth noting that in this format, the `INNER JOIN` is all but useless unless you're using it to check that the same listing exists in both `PCUnitTest.dbo.People` as well as `GMUnitTest.dbo.Contact1`.  If that doesn't matter, then you could simply remove the `INNER JOIN` from this query.

Again, I would like to **caution** you that your `dbo.NameParser()` function seems to always return three rows (ForeName, Middle_Name, Surname).  If this is the case, and if you use it like this in an `INSERT` statement, you will most likely get three rows inserted for every name you parse.

As suggested in my previous answer, you might want to consider adding a second parameter to `dbo.NameParser` so that you can request a specific part of the name.  This would allow you to insert a single row.

I recommend you run just the `SELECT` portion of the above query, without the `INSERT` to see what is returned on a few random entries.  I expect that you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks, yes the last time I used t-sql was in the 90's, so now cross apply was added in 2005. I think it's returning three rows because there are three mathes for that string '76-ENR', I will add the key and see if it still returns 3 rows. Also, this is some code that will be used on the  insert and update trigger. So, I haven't found a way to test the code in a script. I keep writing some test code and then changing it to inserted.
WHERE C.Key1 = '76-ENR'
AND P.PEOPLE_ID = C.KEY4

Comment: When I run the script referencing the inserted table the message displays  'Invalid object name 'inserted'. Is there a way to test code that uses the inserted table in a test script, or is the only way to run it in process?

INSERT INTO SISUnitTest.dbo.People (First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name)
SELECT
     T.ForeName
    ,T.Middle_Name
    ,T.Surname
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN PCUnitTest.dbo.People P
    ON P.People_ID = i.Key4
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(i.Contact) T
WHERE i.Key1 = '76-ENR'
AND P.PEOPLE_ID = i.KEY4

Comment: @ERPise I didn't use the `Inserted` table in my query, because you weren't talking about a `TRIGGER`.  If this is for a `TRIGGER` then the query is different.  There is nothing wrong with the query you posted in your comment for a `TRIGGER`, but the same query can't be run in a stand-alone fashion because you won't have the `Inserted` table available for reference if you're just running it as a regular query.  So is this a `TRIGGER`, or a regular query?

Comment: thanks, i'm testing the logic in this query because i don't know how to test it in a trigger, when i run the script in a trigger the message shows 'Invalid object name 'inserted'.'  this will be for a trigger, so there should only be one record that is updated, so now it is updating three records because there are multiple records in the source table, but when it runs in process there will only be the one record that is updated, so for now i'm just testing that the logic is correct, and then changing the source table to inserted

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error near of here :

```
INSERT INTO       SISUnitTest.dbo.PEOPLE p (p.LAST_NAME, p.FIRST_NAME, p.LAST_NAME)
SELECT           T.ForeName, T.Middle_Name, T.Surnname
FROM             CONTACT1 c
WHERE        (c.KEY1 = p.PEOPLE_ID); //right here
CROSS APPLY dbo.NameParser(c.Contact) T
WHERE p.PEOPLE_ID = c.KEY4
```

remove semicolon from here : `(c.KEY1 = p.PEOPLE_ID);`  <- this semicolon

Comment: thanks, it still shows the error incorrect syntax near cross apply, i have the test tables and data on the paste bin http://pastebin.com/vqW3s6mK